# How do I create a Docker container with a hostname that an other container can use?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, ip, containers, hostname

So I've created a container for RabbitMq with the following command.

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

Which works fine, but I then created another container with the following command

```
docker run test .
```

This runs a container with a PHP file that tries to connect to the hostname, my-rabbit but it can't find it the host so the PHP just closes itself right away. I did, however, find out the IP of the my-rabbit( first container ) and replace the hostname( my-rabbit ) in my PHP code with the IP and it connects with no problems.

So how do I create a hostname for the RabbitMq that all the other container on the same network can see and use instead of an IP?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer after making this post. I use the --link arg with docker run.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links

Comment: Another option would be using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) utility, which essentially does the same, but in much more convenient way.